# Prove the inequality $\left(\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c\right)\left(\frac1{1+a}+\frac1{1+b}+\frac1{1+c}\right)\ge\frac9{1+abc}$

Tags: inequality, radicals, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, rearrangement-inequality

> Let $a,b,c>0$. Prove the inequality
> $$\left(\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c\right)\left(\frac1{1+a}+\frac1{1+b}+\frac1{1+c}\right)\ge\frac9{1+abc}$$

#### My work so far:

Use AM-GM:
$$\frac1{1+a}+\frac1{1+b}+\frac1{1+c}=$$
$$=\frac{\frac1a}{1+\frac1a}+\frac{\frac1b}{1+\frac1b}+\frac{\frac1c}{1+\frac1c}\ge$$
$$\ge3\sqrt[3]{\frac{\frac1a\cdot\frac1b\cdot\frac1c}{\left(1+\frac1a\right)\left(1+\frac1b\right)\left(1+\frac1c\right)}}=$$
$$\ge\frac3{\sqrt[3]{abc}}\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac1a\right)\left(1+\frac1b\right)\left(1+\frac1c\right)}}$$

Comment: Where did you find this problem? As this is pretty clearly a contest-style inequality, what contest is this from?

Comment: Using the HM-GM-AM inequality, we have
$$
\frac 3{HM} = \frac 1a + \frac 1b + \frac 1c \geq \frac{3}{AM}= \frac 9{a + b + c}
$$

Comment: @mixedmath: the problem with the contest from 2008

Comment: which contest 2008?

Comment: http://ru.calameo.com/read/003596578a055905e4b0c

Comment: page 144, No. 786

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Rearrangement

$\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{a}\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{1+a}=\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{a(1+a)}+\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{b(1+a)}+\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{c(1+a)}\geq\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{2}{b(1+a)}+\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{c(1+a)}$.

Now by AM-GM

$(1+abc)\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{b(1+a)}=\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1+abc+b+ab}{b(1+a)}-3=\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(\frac{1+b}{b(1+a)}+\frac{a(1+c)}{1+a}\right)-3\geq$

$\geq2\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a(1+b)(1+c)}{b(1+a)^2}}-3\geq6-3=3$.

By the same way $(1+abc)\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{c(1+a)}\geq3$ and we are done!